# Повторение местоимения

Tags: стилистика

Когда пишу что-то от первого лица, постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой повторения местоимений "я", "мне" и т.д. Где могу, конечно, стараюсь этого избегать, но или я тупая, или это действительно далеко не везде возможно.
Насколько вообще уместно частое повторение местоимения в тексте от первого лица? К примеру, такое предложение - чувствуется ли тут переизбыток местоимения: "Меня трясло, я чувствовал себя той самой лабораторной крысой, которая однажды укусила меня за руку"?
Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласна. Допустимо опускать местоимение, если по контексту понятно, что речь от первого лица. А в настоящем времени глагольное окончание вообще дает нам большой простор, чтобы не пользоваться местоимениями: Смотрю - идет. В вашей фразе я вижу другую проблему. Я бы посоветовала: Меня трясло, я чувствовал себя как та самая лабораторная крыса, которая однажды укусила меня за руку.
А то если герой чувствует себя крысой, он как бы сам себя укусил за руку).

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

"Меня трясло, я чувствовал себя той самой лабораторной крысой, которая однажды укусила меня за руку".

- По-моему, всё на месте,никакой избыточности нет и всё понимается нормально. Чувствовал себя как крыса = чувствовал себя крысой, второе даже более образно и верно передаёт ощущения. Если не будет слова "меня", появится двусмысленность, кого укусила. Так что бывает, что повторов местоимений не избежать, и здесь как раз такой случай. Повтор - не всегда ошибка, иногда это худ. особенность, а иногда он необходим для ясности мысли.

Answer (score 2):

Бывает очень сложно:((( 
Согласна, с предыдущим комментарием, действительно появляется двусмысленность. Чтобы избавиться от повтора, можно развести эти местоимения, добавив больше информации, например, "Меня трясло. Ладони вспотели, глаз дёргался. Я чувствовал себя, как та самая лабораторная крыса, которая однажды укусила меня за руку", или перефразировать, например, "Я был в бешенстве, чувствовал себя, как та самая лабораторная крыса, которая однажды укусила меня за руку".

Answer (score 0):

"я" иногда можно опускать.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за ответы! Вы мне очень помогли!!